# Full-time, out-of-vacation pre-completion F1 Optional Practical Training (OPT) in the USA

Tags: usa, working-visas, students

I see that in some US universities, F-1 PhD students are required to have completed their coursework in order to be eligible for Full-time, out-of-vacation pre-completion F1 Optional Practical Training (OPT):

[Stanford](http://icenter.stanford.edu/students/current/pre_opt.html):

> Ph.D. students who have completed their coursework (except for thesis)
>   are eligible for full-time employment during the academic term.

[MIT](http://web.mit.edu/iso/immigration/emp_f1_opt.shtml):

> Students may apply for pre-completion OPT after completion of all course
>   requirements but before completion of dissertation/thesis.

Is that a legal requirement, or do those Universities simply add more requirements on top of US immigration rules?

Answer (score 1):

This is a legal requirement. During the course of your studies you can work for up to 20 hours on campus.

You can have internships as part of [CPT](http://www.ice.gov/sevis/practical-training) (which comes from the same time quota as the OPT). Universities don't have to allow internships.