# Options to apply full-time (40 hours) CPT or full-time pre-OPT for a F1 student possible?

Tags: usa, working-visas, students

I see in some universities there are options to apply for a full-time pre-OPT for those who have completed all degree coursework requirements except thesis/dissertation. [Some universities with full-time pre-opt discussion thread](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5766/full-time-out-of-vacation-pre-completion-f1-optional-practical-training-opt-i)

Is this common among all universities in the USA or only applicable to specific schools where Universities make this option? I would like to know if there are options to:

1. request full-time CPT in final semester considering all coursework is completed except thesis defense?
2. or can an F1 student request for full-time pre-OPT in the same above situation? (coursework degree requirements completed except thesis defense)